# Error with my vagrant box after upgrading to OSX Mavericks

Tags: vagrant, osx-mavericks

My vagrant version is 1.2.2 and soon after upgrading to OSx Mavericks, there is an error with my vagrant box. I have tried destroying it and restarting it, but doesn't seem to come back up.

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory

VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 68 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Answer (score 2):

You need VirtualBox 4.3.x on Mavericks ([downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)). And support for it was added in Vagrant 1.3.5 ([downloads](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads)). So try upgrading both.

Comment: Thanks for answering. After upgrading both, I have the following error: There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The 'extra' flag on synced folders is now 'mount_options'
* The 'extra' flag on synced folders is now 'mount_options'

Comment: Well, change the flag as the error message suggests. See [the docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) for more details.
Skimming through [the changelog](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) can also be a good idea when upgrading.